# ZF2 Form Element Data Attributes

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

This is more than likely going to be straight forward, or convoluted, but here goes...

How do you add a data attribute to a form element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
$element->setAttribute('data', 'somedata');
```

Comment: You're not quite right; it's [`$element->setAttribute($key, $value)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element.php#L189) not `$element->setAttrib()` (that was ZF1)

Answer (score 0):

Kicking myself right now!

Just remembered I'd already done it previously.

```
...
'attributes' => array(
    ...
    'data-xxx' => '',
    ...
),
```

`>.<`